# Entity Framework update properties, single query, restricted by owner

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to update specific properties, but only if the user owns the entity.

```
//id of user that submitted the request
var userId = User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

_context.MyEntities.Attach(entity);

_context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.myValue).IsModified = true;
```

Is there a way I can make it conditional upon `entity.UserId == userId` without first doing `_context.MyEntities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == entity.Id)` (aka can I handle the update/patch with one query instead of two)?  Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

We've had a great experience using the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) package.
It allows you to update only specified properties *after* your filter is applied.
For example:

```cs
_context.MyEntities
        .Where(e => e.UserId == userId)
        .Update(_ => new MyEntity { MyValue = myValue });
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [`ConcurrencyCheckAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.concurrencycheckattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) the `UserId` property.

Now EF will compare this value on updating and if it is different in the DB then you will receive a [`DbUpdateConcurrencyException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: But would you be able to tell between this and a true `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`?